# Hadoop HDFS : Trash location

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

When and where, `HDFS` creates the `.Trash` folder ?

Does there any rule or logic, any reference ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `HDFS` `.Trash` folder appears after a delete operation (whitout skipping trash) in :

1. For each hdfs user under his home folder:
   `/user/<user-name>/.Trash`
2. For each encryption zone under it's root:
   `/crypto/zone/root/.Trash`

Comment: Ah, yeah, I've not used encryption zones

Answer (score 8):

Every HDFS user has their own `.Trash` folder on HDFS within `hdfs:///user/<name>`. The folder existance is checked and then created whenever `hadoop fs -rm` command gets executed by that user without a `-skipTrash` option.

This is purged on a schedule as per values of `core-site.xml`

- fs.trash.interval
- fs.trash.checkpoint.interval

By default, both are zero, so it is disabled and deleted files will therefore always be recoverable until manually cleared out by an HDFS administrator.

Also see this IBM post on [HDFS Trash](https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/2015/10/22/hdfs-trash/)

Comment: Not only in `/user/<name>`, i can find `.Trash` under other locations !

Comment: Okay, well, I've personally not seen that, so maybe someone manually created the folder. Do you have any examples?